# Distinct terms for 'authentication' and 'validation'? Both seem to be 验证

Tags: vocabulary, technology

Could someone point me to distinct, accurate terms for 'authentication' and 'validation' in Chinese?

This is in a web development context, and I can only find 验证 as the best word for both of them.

When writing about web development, that's quite a big problem as these are both important and distinct concepts.

Some dictionaries give 证明 for authentication, but I get the impression that isn't appropriate for authenticating with a website.

Wikipedia has 身份验证 for authentication, which isn't bad. Currently I'm using 数据验证 for validation and 用户验证 for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

authenticate ＝ 核实

authenticate here means to prove your identity

validate ＝ 验证

captcha is 验证码

Comment: This a message from QQ - using 核实 as authenticate:

尊敬的用户，核实您当前的微博帐号是可以正常使用的，如果手机腾讯微博登录不了，建议您关闭所有后台程序，清理系统垃圾或切换接入点后再换个时间进行登录。